# How to render data of many models on single view on respective button click

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using mvc5 and i have created a Model tableData.cs class which contains code below:

```
namespace WebApplication2.Models
{
    public class tableData1
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }      
        public string Time { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My controller corresponding to it is:

```
namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home

        public ActionResult tableData1()
        {
            ViewBag.NbColumns = 2;
            List<tableData1> tableDataModel = new List<tableData1>();
            tableDataModel.Add(new tableData1()
            {
                Name = "shekha",
                Location = "USA",               
                Time="12:00PM"
            });

            return View(tableDataModel.ToList());
        }    

    }
}
```

And view is:

```
@model  IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Models.tableData1>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "tableData1";
    Layout = null;
}

<div style="width:1300px;">
    <table id="activeDeviceTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" aria-describedby="activeDeviceTable_info">
        <thead>
            <tr role="row">
                <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Name: activate to sort column ascending">Name</th>
                <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Location: activate to sort column ascending">Location</th>              
                <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Time: activate to sort column ascending">Time</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
            <tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <td class="someCssStyle">@item.Name</td>
                    <td class="someCssStyle">@item.Location</td>                   
                    <td class="someCssStyle">@item.Time</td>
                }
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And i have a div in which i render this table using javascript on button click like this:

```
function FirstButtonClick(el)
    {
        $('#tab1').bind('click', function ()
        {        
            var url = 'Home/tableData1';
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: {}, //parameters go here in object literal form
                type: 'GET',
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function (data) { $('div#theNewView').html(data); },
                error: function () { alert('something bad happened in FirstButtonClick'); }
            });
            alert("hello1");
        });
        $('#tab1').trigger('click');
    }
```

And the div in which this view is rendered is:

```
<div id="theNewView" style="float: left; margin: 5px 2px 2px 5px;">     
</div>
```

Now what i want to do ?
  I want to create another model with same fields lets say tableData2.cs and in his controller i will do soemhting  like this:

```
 public ActionResult tableData2()
        {
            ViewBag.NbColumns = 2;
            List<tableData2> tableDataModel = new List<tableData2>();
            tableDataModel.Add(new tableData2()
            {
                Name = "ajeet",
                Location = "allahbad",               
                Time = "1:00PM"
            });
            return View(tableDataModel.ToList());
        }
```

Now i want this controller to replace the data of tableData1 in tableData1.cshtml  to data of tableData2 controller on another button click.

I mean i want to keep only one view(tableData1.cshtml) which contains a table and i want to reuse this view for all my model classes like tableData1.cs and tableData2.cshtml .

Is it possible to do this ? How to do it ?

EDIT: After stefen suggestion i changed the controller code to this:

```
   public ActionResult tableData1()
        {
            ViewBag.NbColumns = 2;
            List<tableData1> tableDataModel = new List<tableData1>();
            tableDataModel.Add(new tableData1()
            {
                filterActiceDeviceList = true,
                filterIdleDeviceList = false,               
                Name = "shekha",
                Location = "USA",               
                Time = "12:00PM"
            });
            tableDataModel.Add(new tableData1()
            {
                filterActiceDeviceList=false,
                filterIdleDeviceList=true,
                Name = "ajeet",
                Location = "allahbad",             
                Time = "1:00PM"
            });           
            return View(tableDataModel);
        }
```

I have added two filters filterActiceDeviceList and filterIdleDeviceList which on true must show the data corresponding to it's table in tableData1.cshtml but i am not able to understand how i will write the code to distinguish the table data in FirstButtonClick() and SecondButtonClick() function (in ajax call)on the basis of these to flags such that each button will show the data corresponding to it's true value.

For example in FirstButtonClick() will show only the data corresponding to filterActiceDeviceList = true which is table in this case will consist of Name: shekha, Location: USA,  Time =12:00PM.

Comment: Note, `tableDataModel` is already List<T>`. You do not have to call `.ToList()` again, especially when you model is only expecting `Enumerable<T>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok thanks ofr suggestion i will keep in mind in future.

Comment: Since your view is `IEnumerable<tableData1>` then you cannot use it for type `tableData2` (they are different types), but since they both appear to have identical properties, why are they different types? If `tableData2()` returned `IEnumerable<tableData1>` then you could do it using `return View("tableData1", tableDataModel);`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I tried to do "return View("tableData1", tableDataModel);" in controller of tableData2 action but it still do not work.

Comment: I as said in my last comment, you cant because the model you create in the `tableData2()` method is `IEnumerable<tableData2>` but `tableData1.cshtml` expects `IEnumerable<tableData1>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke that means there is no solution for this problem ? Do you know any alternative  for this? Actually i have several tabs each on click must show some data in table. so i want one common view (containing html code for table) for all the models.

Comment: If a view declares the model to be a certain type, then you must pass that type to the view. But your code shows that typeof `tableData1` and typeof `tableData2` have identical properties (`Name`, `Location` and `Time`) so why are you using 2 different types? Why cant you just use `tableData1`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have thought of an alternative .Could you please see the edit part of my question ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you doing here. What is wrong with the 2 methods you have and having `tableData2()` initialize `List<tableData1>()` (not `tableData2`) and using `return View("tableData1", tableDataModel);`?